# How do I fix the indentation on the second layer of a custom bullet list and still keep the margin on the first layer? HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to create a custom bullet list (change the bullet color) and adjust the margins of the rows without effecting every row (first row would be 75px, second 15px right of first row). Right now it just makes the first row 75px, then the second row 150px from the border.
html:

```
<div class="vocab">
  <p1>Vocab</p1>
  <div class="list">
     <ul>
        <li>Word</li>
           <ul>
              <li>Definition</li>
           </ul>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.vocab > .list ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
}
.vocab > .list ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the CSS correctly? Your classes are missing the closing brackets.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I updated the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem are the nested lists.
Each of the lists gets a `margin-left: 75px`, which means the second one will be 2 * 75px indented.

I think the best solution would be for you to rethink your markup. Do you really need that second ul element? Maybe a different element would be better? For instance inside the `li` you could have 2 spans, one for the word and another for the word definition.

But if you want to keep that markup, and remove the margin from the second ul, maybe something like this would help you:

```
ul ul {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

This will remove the margin left from any `ul` element which is inside of another `ul` element.
The `!important` is needed because of the specificity of the selectors you are already using

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no clue I could use !important. That solved everything.

Comment: Using `!important` isn't always a good solutions, but in some cases it is a life saver! Glad i could help